# Using an Numpy Index Array with Numba DeviceNDArray

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am naively trying to index into a `cuda` backed DeviceNDArray with a `NumPy` array and getting an error:

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import numba.cuda

In [3]: aa = numba.cuda.to_device(np.arange(10))

In [4]: aa[0]
Out[4]: 0

In [5]: aa
Out[5]: <numba.cuda.cudadrv.devicearray.DeviceNDArray at 0x7f6a647a07f0>

In [6]: aa[1]
Out[6]: 1

In [7]: aa[np.arange(5)]
```

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

For more context, I am in the middle of trying to loading cuda backed arrays through sklearn machinery so we have a mixing of numpy/numba.

Is any indexing possible ?

### Update

Under the hood `DeviceNDArray` calls out to `Dim.__getitem__` which currently only support single item and slice indexing

Comment: So you're starting with the DeviceNDarray?  You could just use `aa.copy_to_host()` to get an `ndarray` back, unless you're trying to avoid making a copy.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am trying avoid making a copy

Comment: Fancy Indexing is currently not supported by Numba -- I have filed an issue and the discussion should move there